# How do I fix "Unidentified Network" on a domain network with static IP addresses?

Tags: active-directory, windows-10, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2019

I am on a work network with Active Directory 2019 and static IP addresses.  We have Windows servers (2008 and 2019), Windows 10 desktop computers, no laptops, and no WiFi.  Lots of security issues, so we're pretty strict.

An additional hurdle is that we are using HID DigitalPersona for MFA authentication.  And yes, it is integrated with Active Directory.

Occasionally, a computer (Windows 10 or Windows server) will show "Unidentified Network, Private Network", in the Network and Sharing Center.  If I restart Windows, it's the same behavior.  No surprise, this causes several file share issues.

If I rejoin the computer to the domain, it goes to "Domain Network", as expected.  But if I restart again, it goes back to "Unidentified Network".

We can not afford to be constantly re-joining the computers to the domain.  Some are servers that are used in production and can not be restarted without affecting production.  And very few users have admin rights to rejoin the domain.  If I re-image one of these computers (suggested by Dell and MickeySoft support), it eventually goes back to the "unidentified network" behavior.

In the network config for all these computers, I have "DNS suffix for this connection" set to the Active Directory domain.  I have 2 DNS servers configured - both are the AD domain servers.

One hack that kind of works is to temporarily switch to DHCP and then switch back and setup the static IP again.  Annoying, and requires admin privileges and starting up DHCP temporarily, but it does work.

I have tried everything on StackOverflow and on most things from the internet that I could find, and nothing has worked consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I recently saw an unrelated blurb about the LanmanWorkstation in the Windows registry, and it has a DependsOnServce entry.  I removed the DependsOnService entry, not the key, and also for the LanmanServer registry key as well.  So far, at least on my test machine, this is working, and it shows "Domain Network", even after several restarts of Windows:

Here is the resultant registry script:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
;
; Remove_DependOnService.reg
;
; Remove the DependOnService entry from the LanmanServer and LanmanWorkstation registry entries.
; This can solve the "Unidentified Network" problem.
;
; You will need to restart Windows after this change for it to take full effect.
;
; 20210413 ByteSlinger - Original.
;

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer]
"DependOnService"=-

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation]
"DependOnService"=-
```

Will this solve my problem long term?  Will it cause other problems?

**UPDATE**

This solves one problem but causes another.  From my test computer I can connect to file shares on the network and the Network Sharing identifies it as a domain network.

But from another computer, I am not able to connect to any file shares on the test computer.  After researching the Workstation Service, I found that the Workstation service is based on the LanmanServer and LanmanWorkstation registry entries.

I will continue to look for a solution.  Hopefully someone will contribute a useful answer to this SO question.